# Перевести код на С

Tags: pascal, c

Помогите перевести данный код на С:

```
var a: array [0..10] of real;
  i,ls,lg,n:integer;
  x,xs,fs,fg:real;
begin

  write('степень');
  readln(n);

  for i:=0 to n do begin
    write('коэффициент при x в степени ',i);
    readln(a[i]);
  end;
  write('x= '); readln(x);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
float a[11];
int i,ls,lg,n;
float x ,xs,fs,fg;
int main()<br>
{
    cout<<"Степень";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"коэффициент при x в степени "<<i;
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    cout<<"x=";
    cin>>x;
}
```

Хочу заметить, что точный перевод будет не очень красиво выглядеть и может быть не самым оптимальным. Лучше так:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a[10];
    int i,ls,lg,n;
    float x ,xs,fs,fg;
    cout<<"Степень";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"коэффициент при x в степени "<<i+1;
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    cout<<"x=";
    cin>>x;
}
```

При такой реализации мы не создаем лишних глобальных переменных  и экономим 1 ячейку памяти (правда, степени будут расположены, начиная с нулевой ячейки до (n-1)). Если необходима большая точность, замените float на double или long double, int можно заменить на long int или long long. Код написан под С++, но должен работать и под С.

Comment: @Василий16, в вашем коде присутствует неточность: в Pascal цикл `for i:=0 to n` проходит по индексам от 0 до 10 _включительно_, так что правильным переводом был бы


    float a[11];
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)

Comment: @Василий16, разумеется, этот странный код под С работать НЕ будет.